# JavaScript sometimes doesn't work in android's webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I put a webview in my application to visit a webpage which includes some javascript functions, my purpose is when users click a link in the webpage, it will start a new activity in the application. I've written "webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);" in my source codes.

It works well in most of the time, however sometimes it doesn't work, there is no response when users click, and I don't know why because the environment is not changed at all. Has anybody know why?

Answer (score 3):

```
v.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber,String sourceID) {
        Log.d("MyApplication", message + " -- From line "+ lineNumber + " of " + sourceID);
        super.onConsoleMessage(message, lineNumber, sourceID);
    }
});
```

check this code so at least you will get error message and one more thing is that android doesn't supports all JavaScript functions.

Comment: I put a breakpoint all over this function and my method never goes in here. I tried before and after my webview loads a page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I changed the event for from 'click' to 'touchstart' and now its awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Credit is due to [Imran Omar Buksh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447429/imran-omar-bukhsh) for this idea.

```
... other HTML ...

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.querySelector("#checkItOut").addEventListener("touchstart", 
            function() {
                jsObject.performClick();
        });
    </script>
</html>
```